# Control Panel for Web App Server?

Tags: linux, web-applications

I'm about to deploy a PHP based web app. I'm looking at purchasing a Linux Box, and I was wondering if I should even bother getting a control panel (cPanel or Plesk).

I'm going to be the only one with access to the box. Any changes I can make on cPanel can be made in linux, right? - If not, what control panel would you recommend for a web app server?

I'm just looking for thoughts and opinions on the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bother. Learn the command-line - you'll be much better off in the long term, knowing how to properly admin your server (and others) without having to rely on the crutch that these GUI control panels provide.

Comment: Thank you Erik! I guess I'll be downloading some manuals! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct that cPanel is just a graphical and shortcut-based frontend. If you're comfortable writing your own shell scripts and using the command line, cpanel is pretty much redundant.

Comment: Thank you DeeDee, I guess I'll be downloading some manuals! :)

Comment: Sure thing! I hoped that answered your question.

If you don't know about "manpages" already, you'll quickly learn to love them. If you're in the command line and you want to learn more about a command, just type "man [command name]" and most of the time you'll get more information than you ever wanted to know!

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that - thank you SO much!

Answer (score -2):

If you want control panel on the box. You could also try the [ispCP Omega](http://isp-control.net/). It's lightweight so it's easy to use  more such cpanel.